# Extract value/name from r Markdown selectInput (drop down menu)

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I extract selected option from r markdown selectInput drop down menu? I have reactive input on my web page something like the following:

```
aggdata <- data.frame(
  "Experiment" = c("One","Two","Three"),
  "AnythingElse" = c(1,2,3)
)

selectInput("Experiment1","Choose the first experiment",
        choices = unique(aggdata$Experiment),
        selected = unique(aggdata$Experiment)[1])
reactiveData <- reactive(as.data.frame(subset(aggdata, Experiment == input$Experiment1)))
firstExperiment_aggData <- reactive(reactiveData())
```

And I'd like to write somewhere to the text reactively, what was user's selection. Do you happen to know, how can I do that. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Shiny is concerned, you could start with this. Does that help you?

```
library(shiny)

aggdata <- data.frame(
  "Experiment" = c("One","Two","Three"),
  "AnythingElse" = c(1,2,3)
)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("Experiment1","Choose the first experiment",
                choices = unique(aggdata$Experiment),
                selected = unique(aggdata$Experiment)[1]),
    tableOutput("table1")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  reactiveData <- reactive({
    return(as.data.frame(subset(aggdata, Experiment == input$Experiment1)))  
    })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    return( reactiveData() )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but actually I'm using r Markdown. How can I do that in r Markdown?

Comment: It is documented here pretty exactly: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_advanced.html
And here is another link: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html